# React Datepicker value date only format

Tags: reactjs, react-datepicker

i have below code

```
          <DatePicker selected={startDate} name="date_of_sale" id="date_of_sale" onChange={date => setStartDate(date)}  dateFormat="dd/MM/yyyy"/>
```

when my date is set to startdate const, it has both date and time as `2020-09-10T17:13:12.071Z`, but i need only date like `10-09-2020`

i have tried `dateformat` attribute to Datepicker , but it is not changing value format, it only for display..

Comment: Are you retrieving this from a database? And if so would it be possible to change the data datatype to short date?

Comment: no, it is new value to add

Comment: Could you use moment and update your state update to date => setStartDate(moment(date).format("dd/MM/yyyy")) ? I know it doesn't solve the issue of the dateFormat prop causing problems. Simply just an alternative to push past it.

Comment: do i need to include any additional module for moment?

Comment: i am using react which doesnt have moment js.. it is not supported in higher version

Answer (score 1):

Are you retrieving this from a database? so you should use Date.parse to parse data to correct format.

```
//setstartDate is a hook(Usestate) to set startDate.

setstartDate(Date.parse(startDate))
```